# how to determine whether a field exists inside a value of a key?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to find all the documents in mongodb which have a "emotion1" key in "emotions" key.
My database structure is like this

```
{
    "word" : "word1",
    "emotions" : 
     {
        "emotion1" : "0.25",
        "emotion2" : "0.25",
        "emotion3" : "0.35"
     }
}
```

I have tried,

```
db.collection.find({"emotions":{"emotion1":{"$exists":True}}})
db.collection.find({"emotions":{"emotion1":{"$exists":True}}})
```

However this works for "emotions", key like this,

```
db.collection.find({"emotions": {"$exists": True}})
```

Comment: db.collection.find({"emotions.emotions1": {$exists: True}}) ?

Comment: yes, this works thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
db.collection.find( { "emotions.emotion1": { "$exists":True } } )
```